# Slack slash command response_type ephemeral are sent to the entire channel

Tags: slack-api, slack

Ephemeral messages are supposed to be only visible to the user that issued the command. However, in my experience, it's sent to the entire channel.

Am I missing anything?

[image]

[image]

According to [Slack Slash commands documentation](https://api.slack.com/slash-commands), the only attribute needed is to set response_type to ephemeral in the response of Node.js app.

The code in my app looks like this:

```
  var t = {
    "response_type": "ephemeral",
    "text": "How to use /please"
  }
    request({
    uri: uri,
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json',
    },
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(t)
  }, function (error, response, body) {

    return res.status(200).end();
  });
```

Comment: Is this actually a response from a slash command? I ask because the screenshot has a bot named "incoming-webhook," which, well, sounds like an incoming webhook. :-) Incoming webhooks don't have a concept of ephemeral messages. (Which user would even see the message?)

Comment: Thanks @smarx. That's correct. The tutorial that I was using had an incoming webhook posting to a channel from the slack slash command. There was no need of the incoming webhook. It took me a while to figure that out. The incoming webhook is always public. The slash command can be either ephemeral or in_channel.

Comment: Here's the tutorial that I was talking about. http://www.sitepoint.com/getting-started-slack-bots/

Comment: So is your issue resolved? (Are you able to get ephemeral messages working from the slash command?)

Comment: Yes @smarx. Thanks for your help. Sorry, for the late response. For whatever reason, I didn't see it.

Answer (score 4):

Ephemeral messages are only supported in slash commands currently. From your screen capture it looks like you're sending your payload to an incoming webhook. Unfortunately, I can't find the wiki that backs this up, but here's another post with a similar answer: [Slack API "attachments" not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38255143/slack-api-attachments-not-showing/38270492#38270492)