# Slack API "attachments" not showing

Tags: python, slack-api

Attachments aren't working in the following code and neither is the `response_type` showing as it should be. I've also tried using Python's Slack Client, but the exact same thing is happening.

```
def send_message(channel_id, text):
    params = {
        "token" : token, 
        "username" : "NEW BOT",
        "channel" : channel_id,
        "text" : text,
        "response_type": "ephemeral",
        "attachments": [{ "text":"This is some text" }]
    }

    headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
    slack_api = 'https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage'
    requests.get(slack_api, json=params, headers=headers)
    return

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def main():
    if sc.rtm_connect():
        sc.rtm_read()
        text = request.args.get("text")
        channel_id = request.args.get("channel_id")
        send_message(channel_id, text)
        return Response(), 200
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `response_type` field can only be set when producing a message in response to a slash command or message button action invocation. It can't be set directly with `chat.postMessage`, as there's no context on the target user for whom to display that ephemeral message.

Another quirk about `chat.postMessage` is that it doesn't currently accept JSON like incoming webhooks does. Instead, you need to send POST parameters of the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` variety. Even quirkier, that `attachments` field actually doesn't get sent as a string of JSON, but URL-encoded into a parameter.

One more tip, with `chat.postMessage` and other write methods, you should use an HTTP POST instead of a GET.

Comment: "Even quirkier, that attachments field actually does get sent as a string of JSON, but URL-encoded into a parameter.". Thanks! That's a pain to found out.

Comment: Great post! For everyone looking for a quick-and-dirty answer, try replacing `"attachments": [{"title": "my title", "text": "my text", ... }]` with `"attachments": json.dumps([{"title": "my title", "text": "my text", ... }])`

Comment: Holy **** . I've been looking for ages. Thanks!

Comment: indeed, this happens to me too. attachments needs to be in JSON string in order to work. ie. `'[{"text": "hello"}]'` instead of `[{"text": "hello"}]`.

Answer (score 2):

```
attachments='[{"title": "Try these - ","text": " Text ", "mrkdwn_in":["text"]}]'
```

Add the title to the attachment. It worked in my case.